# how expect match a pattern with atleast one number,one lower case ,one upper case

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

using Expect how can I check whether the given input has at least one upper case,at least one lowercase and at least one number or "!-%#"? 
For a similar question where the min number of input string is 10, someone answered

```
expect  ^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])([!-%#])*.{10,}$
```

As I'm new to Tcl and Expect, can anyone please explain how the above code works?
Why is it not working if we remove `{10,}` in order to remove the minimum limit?

Comment: So, you just ask how to remove the min limit? Replace `{10,}` with `*`. BTW, the regex will check for *at least one number **OR** "!-%#"*. What do you mean by *optional* in *at least one number and optional "!-%#"*? You may just remove them from the lookahead if you do not require them.

Comment: @Wiktor Actually I need the working of the entire code... and your suggestion worked  for removing the limit...Thanks

Comment: @Wiktor that was a typo...Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The min limit cannot be removed by *deleting* the limiting (bound) quantifier `{10,}`, you need to *replace* it with `*` (to allow empty string) or `+` (to require at least 1):

```
expect  ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).*$
```

or just (since `expect` does not require a full string match):

```
expect  ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])
```

If you need to restrict the symbols to those inside the lookaheads, just replace `.*` with `[a-zA-Z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*`:

```
expect  ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])[a-zA-Z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*$ 
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'd also use greedy quantifiers in a consistent manner in a Tcl regex, although that makes no difference in the current pattern.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - after any 0+ chars there must be an uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - after any 0+ chars there must be an lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])` - after any 0+ chars there must be an ASCII digit, or any of the special symbols defined in the character class
- `.*` - any 0+ characters, as many as possible up to
- `$` - the end of string.

The `(?=...)` constructs are called *positive lookaheads* that "stand their ground", i.e. *do not advance the regex index once they are executed*. Thus, the 3 lookaheads will perform the check one by one, and once one of them returns false, the whole match will be failed.

Note: to avoid unnecessary backtracking with `.*`, you may apply the *principle of contrast* (i.e. using corresponding negated character classes inside the lookaheads):

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*[0-9#?!‌​@$%^&*-])[a-zA-Z0-9#‌​?!@$%^&*-]*$
```

The `[^A-Z]*` will match one or more characters other than uppercase ASCII letters, `[^a-z]*`will match one or more characters other than lowercase ASCII letters, etc. The `.*` grabs the whole string first, and then backtracks, checking if the subsequent subpattern can match. So, negated character classes are much more efficient and find or fail the match quicker.

Comment: I feel like the code should look for upper case preceded by any character in the first part , lower case preceded by any character in the second part, a number preceded by any character in third part and optional !-%# in the last part...Can you please clarify why it isn't like that?

Comment: I added an explanation of how lookaheads work. So, the regex engine will stay at the very beginning and perform 3 checks from the start. Once it gets 3 confirmations that it can match the whole string, it will.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor...helped me a lot as a beginner....Why we use .* at the end since we have completed all our required checks? Also how to modify the code so that it consist of only the above constraints...ie not anything other than,uppercase,lowercase,number and !-#% Currently it can have anything other than this also right?

Comment: You do not really need the `.*$` part  since `expect` does not require a full string match.

Comment: Thank you so much...your suggestions just did it....One more doubt ...As you said  (?=.*[A-Z]) - after any 0+ chars there must be an uppercase ASCII letter , why regex do not consider the characters that we didnt provide, in this 'any 0+ character' ...ie patterns like @@ABC

Comment: Sure...As  I am new to this forum, can you please tell how to upvote....I have  already ticked it....anything else?

Comment: Yes, we can do that, it is called a *principle of contrast*: `^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])[a-zA-Z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*$`. This pattern is the most efficient, as we do not have to backtrack too much when using negated character classes.